# Docker-compose on MongoDB

Tags: python, docker, yaml, cloud

[YML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wGRw.jpg)

So I have my yaml file all written up and am using `docker-compose` and something strange is happening.

When I run compose cmd line, only `mongodb` runs and `mongo-express` doesn't run. If I run compose again then `mongo-express` runs. I know `mongo-express` has to wait on the mongodb server, but why is it not all working at once?

Not a big deal that I have to run command twice, works fine then. But just wondering why. Is this a windows issue? Because my roommate is using a mac with the same yaml and both servers start perfectly on first run.

Answer (score 0):

In your yaml check version. Current latest version is [3.8](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)

It's better to choose an image version also, ex. `image: mongo-express:0.54`

Use `depends_on` under mongo-express

```
mongo-express:
  depends_on: 
    - mongodb
```